# How do I use SPACE instead of TAB in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I just know how to modify the tab width in NSTextView

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[self defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paragraphStyle setTabStops:[NSArray array]];
[paragraphStyle setDefaultTabInterval: tabWidth];
```

But, is there any way to use 4 SPACES instead of TAB in NSTextView?

Answer (score 9):

Well, it's late, but I'll post my answer in case some other poor soul is struggling with this.

I''ve been struggling with this all day, and finally found the answer at [cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/63077-over-riding-the-behaviour-of-the-tab-key-in-nstextview.html)

In summary, what I did was, in my text view delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {
        [aTextView insertText:@"    "];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Seems to work fine.

Undo works also.

Comment: If you subclass `NSTextField` you can override `setTab:` and do it there instead. Useful if you already have a subclass.