# How to change the size of a Text View in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, text-editor, tab-size

I'm making a text editor on Xcode, but I need to know how to change the tab size in a Text View because it's at 8 by default, but I'd like it at 4. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

as per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450982/how-do-i-use-space-instead-of-tab-in-nstextview):

You need to implement this in your [`NSTextViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView:doCommandBySelector:) object.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector 
{
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) 
    {
        [aTextView insertText:@"        "]; //this is 8 spaces
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```